# Listing all the unreferenced existing sub collections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The [documentations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) says the following:

> Warning: Deleting a document does not delete its subcollections!
>
> When you delete a document that has associated subcollections, the
>   subcollections are not deleted. They are still accessible by
>   reference. For example, there may be a document referenced by
>   db.collection('coll').doc('doc').collection('subcoll').doc('subdoc')
>   even though the document referenced by
>   db.collection('coll').doc('doc') no longer exists. If you want to
>   delete documents in subcollections when deleting a document, you must
>   do so manually, as shown in Delete Collections below.

Is there any way I can list all the sub collections that are really in the database (so listing all the unreferenced not-really-deleted (sub)collections)